# Is there a suitable driver to connect a pentax optio s1 camera with ubuntu 16.4

Tags: 16.04, drivers, camera

How can I download pictures from PENTAX optio S1 camerato ubuntu 16.4

Comment: Just connect and it should work!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Every device you connect to the system its mounted like a usb device. You see your camera storage in your file manager (Nautilus). Navigate throgh your device (your camera SDcard) then search DCIM folder. Your photos are likely be there.
Also I'm trying this software for commodity:
https://www.damonlynch.net/rapid/

Comment: I had to install nautilus and can navigate my camera fine now. Tried to download htts://www.damondlynch.net/rapid/  but had problems with the commands.